# How to be sure of the accuracy of HttpClient response?

Tags: java, android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

Please tell me what is the better trick to be sure of a HttpClient response, for example, if we do a login through HttpClient and we need to tell the user of success or failure of his login operation.

Thank you in advance!

PS.: I don't need just to know response Http Status, I need to be sure that I am in the right page after response, example : login.php ==> home.php, if I post my request to login.php, how can I be sure that I am now in hom.php (login success) or I always stay in login.php (login failed)

Comment: Look for Http Status Codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpClient.execute()` is going to return a `HttpResponse`

`HttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` will give you the HTTP response code as an `int`.

See:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html

**Edit to add from comments below:**

You're not using a web browser. The only way you're going to be "on another page" is if you received a `302` redirect and then sent a request for the other page. In which case ... you know which page you have.

If the PHP login script is utterly broken and just returns two different pages depending on whether you logged in or not, you're on your own. Parse the response and hope for the best. More than likely there's going to be a cookie or custom header in the response if that's the case, and you're going to have to look for it.

Comment: I know this, I need to be sure that I am in the right page after response, example : login.php ==> home.php, if I post my request to login.php, how can I be sure that I am now in hom.php (login success) or I always stay in login.php (login failed)

Comment: Um, you're not using a web browser. The only way you're going to be "on another page" is if you received a `302` redirect and then sent a request for the other page. Unless the PHP login script is utterly broken and just returns two different pages depending on whether you logged in or not in which case ... you're on your own. Parse the response and hope for the best. Perhaps there's a cookie you need to look for?

Comment: But you didn't post your comment as an answer to be possible for me to accept it, the solution was in your comment not in your answer !
Please post it as an answer so I can accept it for others !